# "'X' and 'Y' lenghts differ" Error in RStudio

Tags: r

I have a dataset of 503 numbers ranging from -0.8 to 2.7 down one Excel column.  I'm looking to sample the normal distribution by using dnorm through the following:

```
plot(x=seq(from=-1,to=3,by=0.01),
 datNorm2 <- dnorm(x, mean=dat$x[1], sd=dat$x[2]),
plot(datNorm2))
```

where dat$x[1] is the mean and dat$x[2] is the standard deviation of the data.  When I run this, I receive the "'x' and 'y' lengths differ error.  Can someone help me understand why?

Comment: Please provide working code in a reproducible manner. In this case: (1) we don't have `x` or `dat` referenced in the call to `dnorm`; (2) if I contrive of `dat <- list(x=c(2,4))`, I get `Non-numeric argument to mathematical function`. Perhaps just `x <- seq(from=-1, to=3, by=0.1); y <- dnorm(x, mean=2, sd=4); plot(x, y)`? (this was simplified/reduced a little, of course)

Answer (score 0):

The second line of your code doesn't appear correct.  When using the [] in R, the bracket will reference the location of an element in a vector.  For example, [3] will reference the third item in a vector.

I've made some presumptions regarding what you've intended to achieve with your code.  In the end, it is obvious that you intended to create two plots - one plot being the basic data, and the other plot being the distribution.   My interpretation of your code follows:

```
library(repr)
options(repr.plot.width = 5, repr.plot.height = 4)  # To set plot size


x=seq(from=-1,to=3,by=0.01)

print(m <- mean(x))
print(std <- sd(x))
length(x)

par(mfrow = c(1, 2)  )       # To combine two plots

plot(x)
plot(dnorm(x, mean = m, sd = std))
```

[image]